# WebBrowser HtmlElement.GetAttribute("href") prepending hostname

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, mshtml

My Windows Forms application hosts a `WebBrowser` control that displays a page full of links.  I'm trying to find all the anchor elements in the loaded `HtmlDocument` and read their `href` attributes so I can provide a multi-file download interface in C#.  Below is a simplified version of the function where I find and process the anchor elements:

```
public void ListAnchors(string baseUrl, HtmlDocument doc) // doc is retrieved from webBrowser.Document
{
    HtmlElementCollection anchors = doc.GetElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach (HtmlElement el in anchors)
    {
        string href = el.GetAttribute("href");
        Debug.WriteLine("el.Parent.InnerHtml = " + el.Parent.InnerHtml);
        Debug.WriteLine("el.GetAttribute(\"href\") = " + href);
    }
}
```

The anchor tags are all surrounded by `<PRE>` tags.  The hostname from which I'm loading the HTML is a local machine on the network (lts930411).  The source HTML for one entry looks like this:

```
<PRE><A href="/A/a150923a.lts">a150923a.lts</A></PRE>
```

The output of the above C# code for one anchor element is this:

`el.Parent.InnerHtml = <A href="/A/a150923a.lts">a150923a.lts</A>`

`el.GetAttribute("href") = http://lts930411/A/a150923a.lts`

Why is `el.GetAttribute("href")` adding the scheme and hostname prefix (`http://lts930411`) rather than returning the literal value of the `href` attribute from the source HTML?  Is this behavior I can count on?  Is this "feature" documented somewhere?  (I was prepending the base URL myself, but that gave me addresses like `http://lts930411http://lts930411/A/a150923a.lts`.  I'd be okay with just expecting the full URL if I could find documentation promising this will always happen.)

Comment: Good question; but the answer lay in how the browser decides to do what you are seeing.  I can't believe this has anything to do with C# support.  It's just that the browser of choice has decided you get what you get.  I looked at documentation for GetAttribute for both the Browser control and WinForms.Broswer control and there's nothing said about this type of behavior. I've used Seleium a lot and it doesn't do this, even when there is this type of code <base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">

Comment: @JohnPeters As stated in [`IHTMLAnchorElement.href`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869662(v=vs.85).aspx) documents, relative urls are resolved against the location of the document containing the `a` element.

Comment: @RezaAghaei  The link says this: Note  Generally, relative URLs are resolved against the location of the document containing the a element. You can use the base element to control the resolution of relative URLs.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, technically I am not calling `IHTMLAnchorElement.href`; rather, I'm calling `GetAttribute`, which apparently returns the same value, which is frustrating and counter-intuitive.  It means that the default behavior of `GetAttribute` (return the value of the attribute) is being overridden to do something special for href attributes on anchor elements.  That's just plain weird.

Comment: @adv12 Yes you are calling `GetAttribute("href")`, even if you look in attributes collection of the `a` tag `DomElement`, you will see `href` attributes are resolved the same way that stated in `IHTMLAnchorElement.href` document.

Comment: @JohnPeters Using the base element doesn't make sense here. You should have a base tag in the head tag (or insert a base tag in head) to let the browser resolve hrefs based on that address. Hope you find the answer helpful:)

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I agree that that's what's happening.  I just wish that either 1) `GetAttribute()` worked in the standard DOM way or 2) there were documentation stating explicitly that it behaves weirdly like `IHTMLAnchorElement.href`.  In any case, your answer has some good info in it, and the solution you suggest does provide the actual `href` value, so thanks.

Comment: @adv12 You are welcome. I expected `GetAttribute` return the original vaue, but after I saw it returns resolved url and after checking `HtmlElement` and `DomElement` and `IHTMLAnchorElement` and looking into lots of properties and attributes collections, I saw all of `href` related stuffs return resolved url and after reading that document, I changed my way and used the way that you see as answer. I am not sure this is the only way to solve the problem, but I think is't a good one :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I was still hoping for some documentation stating that `GetAttribute` in this case works like `IHTMLAnchorElement.href` and hopefully why, but your answer is the closest I've come and I suppose it doesn't hurt to mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [`IHTMLAnchorElement.href`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869662(v=vs.85).aspx) documents, relative urls are resolved against the location of the document containing the `a` element.

As an option to get untouched `href` attribute values, you can use this code:

```
var expression = "href=\"(.*)\"";
var list = document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
                   .Cast<HtmlElement>()
                   .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.OuterHtml, expression))
                   .Select(x => Regex.Match(x.OuterHtml, expression).Groups[1].Value)
                   .ToList();
```

The above code, returns untouched `href` attribute value of all `a` tags in a document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    foreach (HtmlElement el in anchors)
        {
            string href = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(el.GetAttribute("href"));
            ...
        }
```

Comment: What is this supposed to accomplish for me, and how does it relate to my question?

Comment: Want you get clean link without hostname?

Comment: No, I want either to get the literal value of the href attribute on that element (preferred) or to understand from relevant documentation why GetAttribute() doesn't return that literal value, instead prepending the scheme and hostname.

Answer (score 0):

first reference to Microsoft.mshtml

[image]

```
 using mshtml;      
   var allTagA =  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
   foreach (HtmlElement item in allTagA )
    {
        string href = ((HTMLAnchorElement)item.DomElement).href;
    }
```